# Node.JS Dynamodb memory issue with put

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, amazon-dynamodb

Right now I have this problem with using Dynamodb's put method on the document client. When I run my program right now with the put method commented out, the memory starts at 70MB, jumps to 90MB, then proceeds to settle down to around 65MB. Uncommented out the memory for my program jumps to 90MB and keeps growing constantly.

```
var params;

for (var i = 0; i < tuples.length; i++){
    if(tuples[i][1] != ""){
        params = {
            TableName: "wordTable2",
                Item:{
                    "word":tuples[i][1],
                    "url":tuples[i][0],
                    "info":tuples[i][2]
                }
            };

        var dynamobd = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
        dynamobd.put(params, function(err, data){
            //if(err) console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            //else    console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        });
        dynamobd = null;
        delete dynamobd;
    }
    //console.log(tuples[i][0] + " " + tuples[i][1] + " " + tuples[i][2]);
}
delete params;
delete bodyText;
delete holder;
delete tuples;
```

I do not know how to make an effective for loop to add all items to on parmas. If I could do that I would only have to send one put method for each URL instead of each word which might help. I also tried to put multiple items in the params, as much as 10, but that seems to make little difference.

For the full code go to
https://pastebin.com/iQ1h0jjN

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with instantiating the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()` within the loop. Trying moving that outside of the `for` loop - just below `var params;` should be fine. (Obviously also remove two lines nulling and deleting the dynamodb object)

If that doesn't help, take a look at the DynamoDB [`batchWriteItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property) method. Sounds like you might benefit from this method anyway.

Comment: I tried putting it outside the for loop as well as putting globally no effect. I will look at the batcWriteItem method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the DynamoDB api without any issue but what stands out to me in your code, and which has been mentioned by John Veldboom, is the memory management your doing. The 1st thing I would do is declare and initialize your DynamoDB client early on and never again. Its just a an HTTP rest client under the hood. You should be fine just setting it once along with your other `require('.....')` dependencies

I would also remove all the delete commands and variable assignments to null that your doing. Your for loop completes when its ran through every command but not necessarily after each DynamoDB has returned since those callbacks are being fired asynchronously.

```
var dynamobd = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params;

for (var i = 0; i < tuples.length; i++){
    if(tuples[i][1] != ""){
        params = {
            TableName: "wordTable2",
                Item:{
                    "word":tuples[i][1],
                    "url":tuples[i][0],
                    "info":tuples[i][2]
                }
            };

        dynamobd.put(params, function(err, data){
            if(err) console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            else    console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        });
    }
    console.log(tuples[i][0] + " " + tuples[i][1] + " " + tuples[i][2]);
}
//Your for loop is done but that does not mean all the DynamoDB callbacks have returned yet.
```